# Center asymmetric div in browser

Tags: css, css-position

I have a main div (width: 960px) which is centered in the browser window with "margin: 0px auto". From time to time I would like to show an ad (160x600, margin left side maybe 10px) attached to the right side of the main div but the main div should always remain in the center of the browser.

How can I do that?

Comment: So, your assumption is that all browsers are going to be at least 1300 px wide to be able to accomodate such centering? If not, are you OK with introducing horizontal scrolling?

Comment: If your main container is already centered, just lay your new divider like first inner element of your main-container, then position it absolute with a 'move-it-to-left' position.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the ad inside the centred `div`, make the centred `div` `position:relative`, the ad `position: absolute` and set `left` as appropriate: http://jsfiddle.net/3vqh8/1/

```css
#center {
    background: blue;
    width: 960px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#ad {
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 160px;
    background: red;
    right: -170px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning the main div as relative and the ad div as absolute.

Play with top and left to adjust the placement.

(Not sure it will work, make a jsfiddle to show us your case)

Answer (score 0):

If your main container is already centered, just lay your new divider like first inner element of your main-container, then position it absolute with a 'move-it-to-left' position.

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="new-left-publicity"></div>
    <div class="what-was-there-before"></div>
</div>
```